# How to reach Sublime commands from command palette?

Tags: sublime-text-3

I wan't to use my mouse less, but I don't know all the key-bindings of Sublime Text jet. If I open the `Command Palette` with `ctrl+shift+p` I can type in what I want, but I can't find a lot of tools from the Edit section of Sublime, eg.: `Expand Selection to Tag` or `Duplicate Line`. I know these have keybindings, but until I did not learned them, it would be great to reach them from the `Command Palette`.
Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a package: [Missing Palette Commands](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Missing%20Palette%20Commands) what does exactly this.